# Java Android - AsyncTask with Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, fragment, navigation-drawer

h1, my problem: 
When starting Fragment, it starts to download the file through AsyncTask JSON and after going. Setadapter () in ListView, but if i change Fragment, app crash, because NullPointerException occurs because (Acces error).

How cancel AsyncTask and setAdapter in fragments, when user change ?

Not a lot of code:

Navigation Drawer Fragments Start:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
        android.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SecondFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new OtherFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

Start AsyncTask in Fragment:

```
        new SingleTask(getActivity(), table_name, URL)
        {
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemInfo> item) {
        feed_item = item;
        SetAdapter();
        }
        }.execute();
```

Class with AsyncTask:

```
public SingleTask(Context context, String table, String URLs)
    {
        thisContext = context;
        URL = URLs;
        table_name = table;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ItemInfo> doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            db = new DatabaseStorage(thisContext);
            JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
            dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("data");
            if (getCount(table_name) != 0) { db.onDelete(table_name); }
            for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                String nickname = c.getString("nickname");
                db.insertLabel(nickname, table_name);
                item.add(new ItemInfo(nickname));
            }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        return item;
    }
```

Error Log:

```
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391): Process: com.app.gp, PID: 31391
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at com.app.gp.BoxAdapter.<init>(BoxAdapter.java:34)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at com.app.gp.QuoteFragment.SetAdapter(QuoteFragment.java:140)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at com.app.gp.QuoteFragment$1.onPostExecute(QuoteFragment.java:83)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at com.app.gp.QuoteFragment$1.onPostExecute(QuoteFragment.java:1)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-11 11:54:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(31391):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

QuoteFragment its SecondFragment

Comment: Can you show the source code?

Comment: Can you also show the error log?

Comment: yes, i update first post

Comment: This is because another task begins, and the first task is no longer have access.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a reference to the AsyncTask that is currently executed. Then, in the Fragment's onStop() method (or whenever the task is no longer useful, for example if you want to discard it and run a new one) call [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) on the task.

This will prevent the  onPostExecute() method from firing for that task.